# A JavaScript Function i created changes the first and last name but also checks to see if there is a space between the names but is not working

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to JavaScript and am learning of a book but the book is rather dated (2003) I am trying to get the function to execute the rest of the function but even when I have spaced the first and last name it executes the part of the function that tells the viewer that there is no space between the first and last names.
Code for reference

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      function getname() {
        var the_text = window.prompt("Enter Your First and last name", "");
        if (the_text.indexOf(" ") == -1) {
          window.alert(
            "Put a space between your first and last name. Try again."
          );
          getname();
        }
        var split_text = the_text.split(" ");
        if (split_text[0].charAt(0) != "Z" || split_text[0].charAt(0) != "z") {
          var shorter_fn_string = split_text[0].substring(
            1,
            split_text[0].length
          );
          new_fn_name = "Z" + shorter_fn_string;
        } else {
          var shorter_fn_string = split_text[0].substring(
            1,
            split_text[0].length
          );
          new_fn_name = "w" + shorter_fn_string;
        }
        if (split_text[1].charAt(0) != "Z" || split_text[1].charAt(0) != "z") {
          var shorter_ln_string = split_text[1].substring(
            1,
            split_text[1].length
          );
          new_ln_name = "Z" + shorter_ln_string;
        } else {
          var shorter_ln_string = split_text[1].substring(
            1,
            split_text[1].length
          );
          new_ln_name = "W" + shorter_ln_string;
        }
        window.alert(
          "now your name is" + new_fn_name + " " + new_ln_name + "!"
        );
      }
      getname();
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to reduce your code and it runs as expected. Your mean your code prints out `Put a space between your first and last name. Try again.` even when you have a space in between?

```js
function getname() {
  var the_text = window.prompt("Enter Your First and last name", "");
  if (the_text.indexOf(" ") == -1) {
    window.alert(
      "Put a space between your first and last name. Try again."
    );
    getname();
  }
  console.log(the_text.split(" "));
}

getname();
```